# Detecting Injection in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I'm using Hibernate and I want to prevent injections into Hibernate prepared statements.
Is there a straightforward way to do this?
Regards,
Hamed

---

Let me rephrase my problem. :-) I have a lot of queries in my code which are in form: session.createQuery(...). There are two kinds of queries. those who have setParameters, and those who does not have. The latter is in form: select * from XYZ where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'" which is not suitable for me. Now, my problem is how I can find second form automatically. Do I have any solution?

Comment: Hibernate only uses prepared statements. Why do you care?

Comment: Yeah, but some sort of queries are still vulnerable against injection. I want to detect those.

Comment: So, the question is not accurate.  You are not interested in Prepared Statements in Hibernate.  You want to stop SQL Injection.

Comment: You're right. Let me rephrase my problem. :-)
I have a lot of queries in my code which are in form:
session.createQuery(...).
There are two kinds of queries. those who have setParameters, and those who does not have. The latter is in form:
select * from XYZ where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'"
which is not suitable for me.
Now, my problem is how I can find second form automatically. Do I have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you up your logging to DEBUG, you can see what Hibernate is doing.  It outputs statements indicating what it's doing with Prepared Statements, including when it reuses them.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but I didn't mean in that way.
I want to inspect them at runtime in my code, not at log level.
Can you help me in that way?

Comment: Not sure exactly why you want to do this, but if you are running your app locally in Eclipse and have the Hibernate source attached, you can step through the code in the Debug perspective and see where it grabs Prepared Statements.  If you are looking for a programmatic way to do this, I got nuthin.

Comment: I want to filter those queries like this:
"select * from XYZ where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'". You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to up your logging (see @Aaron Sheffey) and turn on show sql. Here is the property to set.

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

See here for more details on the logging you can do: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging

The following log4j properties will place the Hibernate statements into their own file as well.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, org.hibernate

log4j.appender.org.hibernate=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.DatePattern=-yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.File=${catalina.base}/logs/hibernate.log
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.org.hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: I put a comment for Aaron, then I decided to put it here. Thanks James, But log files doesn't help me. I want that inspection to occur at runtime so I can detect & manipulate those queries in my code. Can you give me a hint in that manner?

Comment: No. I'd be hesitant to do that sort of manipulation. If, as you said above, you're worried about SQL injection I suggest you make sure you are escaping your parameters properly before they get anywhere near Hibernate.